# Undeclared type: createM3FromEclipseProject (Rascal)

Tags: import, abstract-syntax-tree, rascal

In the following module, I tried to add myModel for debugging purpose to see the AST.

```
module FlowGraphsAndClassDiagrams

import analysis::flow::ObjectFlow;
import lang::java::flow::JavaToObjectFlow;
// Added to check the M3 model
import lang::java::jdt::m3::AST;

import List;
import Relation;
import lang::java::m3::Core;

import IO;
import vis::Figure; 
import vis::Render;
import analysis::m3::TypeSymbol;
alias OFG = rel[loc from, loc to];
//To view the M3 model from the whole eclipse project
alias myModel = createM3FromEclipseProject(loc project);
....
```

When I import the above module in the rascal console, I get the following error:

```
Reloading module FlowGraphsAndClassDiagrams
|console:///|:Could not load FlowGraphsAndClassDiagrams
|console:///|:could not reimport FlowGraphsAndClassDiagrams
|project://my_project/src/FlowGraphsAndClassDiagrams.rsc|(428,26,<18,16>,<18,42>): Undeclared type: createM3FromEclipseProject
Advice: |http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Errors/Static/UndeclaredType/UndeclaredType.html|
```

I don't understand what the mistake is.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies with

`alias myModel = createM3FromEclipseProject(loc project);`

What are you trying to achieve with this alias? I think you don't want to use an alias, instead you want to do this:

`m = createM3FromEclipseProject(|project://eLib|);`

`println(m);`

Comment: I just want to add a variable say m = createM3FromEclipseProject(loc project);

and print it.

Comment: myModel = createM3FromEclipseProject(loc project);
I'm getting a parse when declaring it in my project. Whereas, it works in my console.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Declarations/Alias/Alias.html

You can use `alias` to create a new name for *types*, while `createM3FromEclipseProject(loc project)` seems to be a declaration of a function. If you want to *call* a function, which you seem to be doing, you need to provide a variable/value as parameter: `createM3FromEclipseProject(|project://eLib|)` if you want to "create an M3" from eclipse project "eLib".

Answer (score 1):

Both answers are right, you can't use aliases for global variables. If you want to make an global variable (which in most cases we advice against), you have to give the type of that variable. We only allow type inference for local variables.

So in your specific case it should be:

```
M3 myModel = createM3FromEclipseProject(|project://eLib|);
```

In most cases you want to do this in your main method instead of at module import time.